# Issues using Snort on Ubuntu

Tags: snort

I installed snort on `Ubuntu 14.04` but am having issues seeing the alerts. I also want it to log the alerts to a `GUI` but am having issues also with `MySQL` database. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your installation running `snort -v`. Make sure you run snort as root user or else you will get an error as shown below.

```
Running in packet dump mode

    --== Initializing Snort ==--
Initializing Output Plugins!
ERROR: Failed to lookup interface: no suitable device found. Please specify one with -i switch
Fatal Error, Quitting..
```

If `snort -v` is working then try running the basic IDS mode using

```
snort -d -l ./log -c snort.conf
```

where `log` is the **directory** where you want to store the log and alert files. `snort.conf` is the name of your snort configuration file. It should contain the your snort rules.

> If you don’t specify an
>   output directory for the program, it will default to /var/log/snort

Here is the manual. https://www.snort.org/documents/snort-users-manual